# Get Exif metadata of images with pillow (python) not working

Tags: python, python-imaging-library, exif

Recently I made a python script to collect metadata (specifically XPKeywords - 40094) to create new directories. The code works, but ONLY for a few images, and I really can't tell why it works only with some of them even if both have data in the field.

Here's part of the code:

```
def getStudents(img):
    tags = ""
    tagsArray = []
    # extract EXIF data
    exifdata = img.getexif()

    print(exifdata)
```

Stack Overflow won't let me import the images, but both of them shows data when oppening the properties of the image.

This is the result for the image that works (see that it shows the 40094 tag):

```
.......41985: 0, 34855: 1600, 41986: 1, 34864: 2, 42033: '3074664', 42034: (18.0, 135.0, 3.5, 5.6), 42036: '18.0-135.0 mm f/3.5-5.6', 41991: 2, 41992: 0, 41993: 0, 296: 2, 282: 240.0, 272: 'NIKON D7000', 305: 'Adobe Lightroom 
5.5 (Windows)', 306: '2022:10:08 12:21:22', 283: 240.0, 40094: b'B\x00B\x00;\x005\x006\x004\x001\x001\x002\x00;\x005\x006\x004\x000\x002\x003\x00;\x005\x006\x004\x001\x003\x006\x00;\x005\x006\x004\x001\x006\x000\x00\x00\x00', 271: 'NIKON CORPORATION'}
```

This is the result for the image that DOESN'T works (we can't find the 40094 tag):

```
{34665: 246, 36864: b'0231', 37377: 6.643856, 37378: 4.970854, 36867: '2022:05:17 21:59:06', 36868: '2022:05:17 21:59:06', 37380: 0.3333, 
37381: 3.9, 37383: 3, 37384: 0, 37385: 13, 37386: 24.0, 40961: 1, 41987: 0, 41988: 1.0, 41989: 36, 41990: 0, 36880: '-03:00', 37521: '98', 37522: '98', 41994: 2, 41996: 0, 41495: 2, 41728: b'\x03', 33434: 0.01, 33437: 5.6, 41729: b'\x01', 34850: 1, 34855: 1000, 41986: 1, 42034: (0.3180051591872787, 2.776876470278045, 1.7411793192274527, 2.236174170759503), 42036: '0.3-2.8 mm f/1.7-2.2', 41991: 2, 41992: 0, 41993: 0, 296: 2, 282: 240.0, 272: 'NIKON D7200', 305: 'Adobe Lightroom 6.0 (Windows)', 306: '2022:11:01 23:27:13', 315: 'Author', 34853: {0: b'\x02\x02\x00\x00', 1: 'N', 2: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 3: 'E', 4: 
(0.0, 0.0, 0.0), 6: 0.0, 11: 0.0, 19: 'E', 20: (0.0, 0.0, 0.0)}, 283: 240.0, 271: 'NIKON CORPORATION'}
```

I already tried downgrading the PIL module, already tried with another python module (piexif) and the result in all tests are the same.
Does someone have any idea why is that happening? One thing that I realized is that the Adobe Lighroom version differs from one imagem to another, and maybe that's causing the problem, but it still doesn't make sense for me.
Thanks in advance!

EDIT:

I realized that if I change the Keywords manually (file properties -> details) the code works. But if I receive the images and try to run without changing it, it doesn't work. Maybe it's something related to permissions, but in the security tab all the items are checked. It's like the fact of changing it, kind of "unlocks" the file and just after doing it I can see all metadata in the python code.

Comment: How do you know that these images have the EXIF data you require? Maybe it wasn't saved with it last time it was saved.

Comment: Unfortunately I coundn't upload any images showing it, but when I open the image properties the data is clearly there, but it doens't appear when I run the code. I found an example of what I mean, look at the "Tags" field ---> https://i.stack.imgur.com/PDvhD.png

Comment: "Tags" (aka keywords) don't imply Exif - it could be IPTC or XMP, too. Also please edit your question instead of adding details in comments.

Comment: The "details" I gave in the previous comment are in the question already. There is no additional information in what I said.

Comment: You can share images unmodified via Google Drive or Dropbox or others.